# TotalCommander: a button to run a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, total-commander

could anyone give me a hint how to configure a TotalCommader UI panel button to run a batch file residing at some location, say `C:\scripts\batch.bat`?

I literally need contents of button config screen, for ex. what do we put in `Command` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you already have the .bat file.

Following your example, in Total Commander, go to C:\scripts. Click on the batch.bat file, and drag it onto Total Commander's button bar.

That will create a new button which will run the batch.bat file when clicking on it.